# Modifying PowerBIIntegration.Data fields from PowerBI without restarting PowerApp canvas from scratch

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

Am pulling multiple fields into PowerApps from PowerBI via the PowerBIIntegration.Data.(Value) connection.

I realised after designing the whole app that I was calling a 'Count' summary rather an 'Average' summary of the metric I wanted. Having modified this, I can no longer retrieve that data - the connection seems to be broken.

Previously on a separate occassion, I added a field in PowerBI after finishing the app, and again, I could not retrieve the field in PowerApps, I could only retrieve the initial fields I had added. It seems as if there is a snapshot of fields when you first make the app, and this can't be modified.

I don't want to rebuild the app a third time if I don't have to!

Is there a way to refresh this?

Yep, I have tried PowerBIIntegration.Refresh().

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Publish the dashboard to the PowerBI service with the new fields.

Click the 3 dots in the top corner of the PowerApp, and click edit.

This will take you to the browser/development space for the app.

New/updated/renamed fields are now included/reflected.